# Flutter ListView becomes sloppy and slow when using RadioListTile or Radio buttons in each item

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-radiobutton

I am trying to implement a listview where I will show the questions of a quiz and each questions will have 4 radio buttons. But when the list gets bigger like 30-50 items the listview scroll becomes very sloppy and laggy. without radio but only text scroll works smooth. Please help me if you have faced similar issue.

I tried to use SingleChildScrollview on top of Listview but I didn't get any solutions. I think the problem is with Radio. I dont why this widget is so heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the ListTile/RadioListTile/Radio components from my ListView children and created a radio using IconButton which made my ListView smoother. I think the default Radio made my ListItems more complex as they have their own states which may be cost expensive. I wish I could use itemExtent which makes the scroll lot faster than it is right now.

Answer (score 2):

- first : Its BAD PRACTICE to wrap a `ListView` with `SingleChildScrollView`. read this article, i just summarize about it : [article](https://medium.easyread.co/my-october-flutter-notes-2-6e0c78cf2e56)
- for better performance use `ListView.buildder`. I also explain on that article

but for more refrerence you can read this official documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists

antoher tips:
set the `itemExtent` value for `ListView`. It will improve the performance of flutter apps.

```
ListView(
 children: widgets,
 itemExtent: 200,
```

- left : without itemExtend ( arround 10second to get index 999) ,
- right : with itemExtend (very fast move to index 999)

[image: Without itemExtend]  [image: with itemExtend]

read this article for another implementation: [link](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-flutter-app./)

Comment: I will give it a try to that itemExtent and let you know.

Comment: Using itemExtend really enhances the performance of a listview but it won't work for me. itemExtend property defines the height of each item in the listview, which can be applied when we know the height of children in the listview. But, in my case, the children's height is dynamic and depends on the contents of each child.

Comment: that will caused expensive

Comment: Yes, I have to find strategies to reduce the list size. But I must keep the children's height dynamic.